# Как найти все файлы, кроме файлов с расширением .docx?

Tags: windows, поиск, проводник

Проблема. Подскажите, как найти файлы с любым расширением, кроме .docx, в проводнике windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строку поиска нужно ввести следующее:

```
*.* NOT *.docx
```

`*.*` означает поиск любых файлов, а ключевое слово NOT исключает из поиска именно файлы с расширением DOCX